# GraphQL schema file should contain a valid GraphQL introspection query result

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, graphql, apollo

I have successfully installed Apollo in my project and i have successfully downloaded schema.json from my endPoint. After buliding my project for creating API.swift error is displayed.

The Error is **GraphQL schema file should contain a valid GraphQL introspection query result**

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Need more detail

Comment: what more detail you want?

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: Thanks for your response sir. i was found solution for this problem.This problem based on schema.json.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the correct `schema.json` and `your_query.graphql`, make sure all value in `your_query.graphql` able in `schema.json`

You download your schema using the apollo [CLI](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling#apollo-schemadownload-output)